# How to Center a BeamerColorBox

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment

The question is, how to horizontally center a `beamercolorbox` on the page?

I put it in the `center` environment, but that doesn't work.

```
\setbeamercolor{bgcolor}{fg=black,bg=blue}
\begin{center}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[rounded=true, center=true, shadow=true, wd=6cm]{bgcolor}
        Some text goes here...
    \end{beamercolorbox}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Glad you liked my answer.  Next time it might be better to hold off clicking the check mark in case someone else comes by with a better one.  I usually give it a day so I can determine which of several answers is best.

Comment: @Matthew: I was so excited with you clever and succinct answer that I couldn't help but to accept it! Yet your advice is wise and I'll stick to it next time.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`wd=<dimen>` not only sets the width of the `beamercolorbox` to `<dimen>`, it sets the `\hsize` to `<dimen>`.  So you're centering a box in a line which has the same width as the box, resulting in nothing.

So to force centering, use some `\hfill`s:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercolor{bgcolor}{fg=black,bg=blue}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\hfill
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[rounded=true, center, shadow=true,wd=6cm]{bgcolor}
        Some text goes here...
    \end{beamercolorbox}
\hfill\hfill
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I'm not sure why you need two at the end—it seems like one at the front and back would do the centering.  But instead you just get a box flush right.  So an extra one does the trick.

Comment: Well, you are more creative than me. I used one `\hfill` before and another after `beamercolorbox`, and got the flush right effect. I'd never imagine of using two `\hfill`!

Comment: @Sadeq @Matthew: `\hspace*{\fill}` at the end of the frame forces centering.

Comment: `\hfill` followed by `\par` (or equivalent) does nothing.  Doubling the `\hfill` means that the first is no longer followed by `\par` so it does something.  The second does nothing as it is followed by (something equivalent to) `\par`.  So `\hfill{}` would work just as well.

Comment: @Andrew: OK, that makes sense.  `\par` eats glue.  `:-D`

Comment: That ought to be a slogan for _something_!  It's almost worth setting up a site just so that the tag-line could be "`\par` eats glue".

Answer (score 8):

Here's an answer that keeps the `center` environment:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercolor{bgcolor}{fg=black,bg=blue}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{center}
~
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[rounded=true, center, shadow=true,wd=6cm]{bgcolor}
        Some text goes here...
    \end{beamercolorbox}
~
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Matthew's answer gave me the hint.  The trick is to ensure that the colour box is not the *only* thing on the line that is being centred.  Then it isn't treated as a box by itself, but as a component of something larger.  So then the search is on for something to put on the line that won't be seen in the final output.  If it has non-zero width, then it needs to be put before and after to ensure that the centring is still central.  A non-breaking space (`~`) seemed the simplest thing to do.

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution, which is slightly less messy for my taste, is to create a single column, which is automatically centered:

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\column{.7\linewidth}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[rounded=true, center, shadow=true]{bgcolor}
    Some text goes here...
  \end{beamercolorbox}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

Experience shows that one needs at least one more column eventually, anyway ;)