# Where is the trailing space after TikZ node text gone?

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing

I've been fiddling with `TikZ` nodes to get framed text (part of `mdframed` boxes, but that's beside the point) when I discovered something that puzzles me. If you run the code below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
with \verb|TikZ|:

\tikz{\node[draw]{t};}

\tikz{\node[draw]{t~};}

\tikz{\node[draw]{t~~};}

with \verb|\framebox|:

\framebox{t}

\framebox{t~}
\end{document}
```

you get:

[image]

I keep wondering where the first space (`~`) behind the `t` goes? On the contrary, `\framebox` seems to respect this mandatory space.

What's happening here?

Comment: I got the same effect with `~` replaced by `\ `

Comment: Maybe related to the "`\par` eats glue" discovery in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6372/1402)?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Not `\par` eats glue: `\unskip` eats glue.

Comment: TikZ removes spaces to save you from writing `%` all over the place. Is there a real use-case scenario behind this question?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: There is: I've been recreating (with modifications) the fancy [example](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed/mdframed-example-tikz.pdf) from `mdframed` with `TikZ` with the boxed title for the frame. If you look, even there, the title is followed by one `~` to have a nice spacing, but this results in nothing. Finally you end up with a wider space at the beginning of the title than at its end. Not really a beauty to behold (especially with larger font size).

Comment: @David: Thanks for setting the record straight!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When in doubt add `\tracingall`. If you modify your input to say

```
{\tracingall\tikz{\node[draw]{t~};}}
```

For the second case you get the log below,

```
~->\nobreakspace {}

\nobreakspace ->\protect \nobreakspace  
{\relax}

\nobreakspace  ->\leavevmode \nobreak \ 

\leavevmode ->\unhbox \voidb@x 
{\unhbox}

\nobreak ->\penalty \@M 
{\penalty}
{\ }
{begin-group character {}
{end-group character }}
{end-group character }}
{restoring \tikz@align@header=undefined}
{restoring \graph=macro:->\path graph}
{restoring \datavisualization=macro:->\tikz@lib@datavisualization }
{restoring \calendar=macro:->\tikz@lib@cal@calendar }
{restoring \matrix=macro:->\tikz@path@overlay {node[matri\ETC.}
{restoring \coordinate=macro:->\tikz@path@overlay {coordinate\ETC.}
{restoring \node=macro:->\tikz@path@overlay {node}}
{restoring \useasboundingbox=macro:->\path [use as bounding box]}
{restoring \clip=macro:->\path [clip]}
{restoring \shadedraw=macro:->\path [shade,draw]}
{restoring \shade=macro:->\path [shade]}
{restoring \filldraw=macro:->\path [fill,draw]}
{restoring \fill=macro:->\path [fill]}
{restoring \pattern=macro:->\path [pattern]}
{restoring \draw=macro:->\path [draw]}
{restoring \againpath=macro:#1->\pgfextra {\pgfsyssoftpath@getcurrentpath \ETC.
}
{restoring \path=macro:->\let \tikz@signal@path =\tikz@signal@path \ETC.}
{restoring \stopscope=macro:->\tikz@atend@scope \iftikz@transparency@group \ETC
.}
{restoring \startscope=macro:->\pgfutil@ifnextchar [\tikz@@scope@env \ETC.}
{restoring \endscope=macro:->\tikz@atend@scope \iftikz@transparency@group \ETC.
}
{restoring \scope=macro:->\pgfutil@ifnextchar [\tikz@@scope@env \ETC.}
{restoring \pgfsysprotocol@temp=macro:->{q }}
{restoring \pgf@colnext=\relax}
{restoring \pgf@coltest=macro:->}
{restoring \pgf@colmarshal=macro:->\pgfsys@color@gray {0}}
{restoring \\color@pgf@tempcolor=macro:->\xcolor@ {}{0 g 0 G}{gray}{0}}
{restoring \reserved@c=macro:->\XC@definec@lor []{pgf@tempcol\ETC.}
{restoring \@let@token=the letter n}
{restoring \reserved@b=macro:->\XC@definec@lor []{pgf@tempcol\ETC.}
{restoring \reserved@a=macro:->\XC@definec@lor []{pgf@tempcol\ETC.}
{\unskip}
```

Which shows that after expanding `~` Tikz ends a group (and so TeX restores a load of definitions) and the the unskip primitive (from `\unskip`) removes the space.

This is similar to the LaTeX definition of `tabular` cells which use `\unskip` to remove trailing spaces in the content but LaTeX box commands do not do this. Note `\unskip` only removes one skip so `~~` the second one is removed but the first remains.

Comment: Ok, so this means I just have to add two `~`s if I want to addend a visible space?

Comment: @CountZero Try this one `\node (a) at (0,0) {A      \  \  \   \   \   \  A};`

Comment: Baaah I can't put more spaces in between. Fortunately TikZ does the same :). Consecutive spaces are eaten.

Comment: @CountZero You can protect yourself from `\unskip` by using `~\hbox{}` or `hbox{~}`  or `~\kern\z@` according to taste.